# cakephp3 admin prefix for webroot directory

Tags: cakephp

I have cakephp3 application and i created a prefix named admin

so as cakephp doc said i created a directory in Template and Controller .

now i want to do the same thing for css and images in webroot but as soon as move the files in Admin directory in webroot cakephp don't recognise them.

my (css , js ) files for admin panel and main site are completely different and i want them apart.

how can i move the files (css , js , etc ) for admin prefix in Admin directory

### **update**

Adding `../Admin/css/` before the style name (for css ) is the only way i found working but it isn't clean . I appriciate any idea's thanks

Answer (score 0):

I use an extra admin layout (/src/Template/Layout/admin.ctp). 
In this Layout I add the css and Javascript files for the admin views (e.g echo $this->Html->css('admin/style.css');)
In the admin controllers i add a beforeFilter method to load the admin layout for all actions:

```
/**
* @param Event $event
* @return \Cake\Http\Response|null|void
*/
public function beforeFilter(Event $event)
{
    parent::beforeFilter($event);
    $this->viewBuilder()->setLayout('admin');
}
```

Comment: Thanks . actually i have different layout for admin . I want to know that is there a way that i do not need to add admin prefix to my style manually like this $this->Html->css('admin/style.css'). because i'm in the middle of the project and i wrote all styles like this $this->Html->css('style.css')  and then i decided to use prefixes for admin . is there a way to prevent manually edit for all these files ??

Comment: No, as far as I know you have to add the prefix in every css and script request.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this! try the below code

```
<?php echo $this->Html->css('/admin',null,array('inline' => false)); ?>
```

Comment: can you explain how should i use this .  for example this is how i included my css before moving files to Admin directory                                                                                 <?= $this->Html->css([ 
    'css_1' ,
    'css_2' ,
    'css_3' ,
]) ?>